# Save past GNU screen output to a file

Tags: logs, gnu-screen

I have had a GNU screen session running for days. I find myself in the situation that I need to save the terminal contents (which I can scroll up to see) into a file.  Is this possible? I estimate it to be below 5000 lines.

I found a way to set up screen to log *future* output to a file. But in this case, I need to also save past output (or as much of it as is present).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `hardcopy -h` command to save the contents of the current scroll buffer
to a file.  As described in `man screen`:

> ```
>    hardcopy [-h] [file]
>
>    Writes out the currently displayed image to the file file, or,
>    if no filename is specified, to hardcopy.n in the default
>    directory, where n is the number of the current window.  This
>    either appends or overwrites the file if it exists. See below.
>    If the option -h is specified, dump also the contents of the
>    scrollback buffer.
> ```

You said:

> I estimate it to be below 5000 lines.

5000 lines is really a lot. The default length of scroll buffer in
`screen` is just 100, not ~5000 lines.  Unless you started your
`screen` session with a larger scroll buffer setting it will not be
possible to retrieve all ~5000 lines of the scroll buffer.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I can scroll back about 1500 lines ... I did not change the size of the scrollback buffer.

Comment: The command can be entered when before `^a :` has been pressed.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it is to use copy mode to copy the entire scrollback history, then dump it into a file.  (There is likely a better way.)

With default keybindings, this would be something like:

- Ctrl-A to send screen a command
- `[` to enter copy mode
- `g` to go to the top
- Space bar to mark the beginning of the scrollback buffer (where you are) as the start of the text to be copied
- `G` to go to the end
- Enter to mark the end of the text to be copied, and copy it.

Then open up vim, run `:set paste` to avoid issues with e.g. auto-indentation, and then use `Ctrl-A` `]` to paste.

Comment: Couldn't you achieve the same with `hardcopy`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk please write an answer.  :)  I just wrote this off the top of my head, I didn't check the documentation for the better way, but that's probably it.

Comment: I posted an answer but it still doesn't answer OP's question to be honest. I'm not sure it's possible to retrieve 5000 lines of scroll buffer, at least using default settings.

Comment: I accepted this one because `harcopy` is not present on this system and I do not have root access to easily install it.

Comment: @Szabolcs: `hardcopy` is not an external program, it's `screen` command

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Oops ... that should have been clear to me from when you said "As described in `man screen`" ...